# Relation between EM scalar potential and EM vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, potential, field-theory, classical-electrodynamics

I am doing caculation using $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$, however I can't find the relation between $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$. For E and B we have

\begin{align}
\frac{{{d^2}E\left( x \right)}}{{d{x^2}}} + \frac{{{\omega ^2}}}{{{c^2}}}E\left( x \right) &= 0\\
\frac{{{d^2}B\left( x \right)}}{{d{x^2}}} + \frac{{{\omega ^2}}}{{{c^2}}}B\left( x \right) &= 0
\end{align}

in vacuum for 1-D case. Given $E(0) = E_0$ and $E'(0) = ik E_0$, the solution for E is $E(x) = E_0 e^{ikx}$. And we can find solution for B is $B(x) = \frac{E_0}{c} e^{ikx} $ for there is $|E|=c|B|$ in SI unit.

But I can't find the realtion between $A$ and $\phi$ similar to E and B for 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial t^2} - \nabla^2{\varphi}  &= 0\\
\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\mathbf A}{\partial t^2} - \nabla^2{\mathbf A} &= 0
\end{align}

using Lorenz gauge.

What is the relation between $A$ and $\phi$ besides gauge condition?

Comment: If E and B are time-independent, why do you think there is *any* relationship between them?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the relation between A and ϕ besides gauge condition?

Maxwell's equations in vacuum are, in terms of $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$:

$$\nabla^2\phi + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}\right) = 0$$

$$\left(\nabla^2 \mathbf{A} -  \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{A}}{\partial t^2}\right) - \nabla\left(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} +  \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right) = 0 $$

Since $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}$ and $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}$ are gauge degrees of freedom, it looks like the answer to your question is *none*.

Comment: Thank you. The first equation you wrote, ${\nabla ^2}\phi  + \frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {\nabla  \cdot {\bf{A}}} \right) = 0$, give me some clue. With plane wave  assumption, we can find a relation. However there is none without plane wave assumption as you said.

Answer (score 1):

If ${\bf A}$ satisfies a homogeneous wave equation of the form suggested, then
$${\bf A} = {\bf A_0} f({\bf k}\cdot {\bf r} - \omega t)$$
is a solution, with $\omega/k=c$.

In that case, I think that you can write
$$ \phi = \frac{c^2}{\omega} {\bf k}\cdot {\bf A} = \frac{c^2}{\omega} {\bf k}\cdot {\bf A_0}f,$$
which is also a solution to the homogeneous wave equation for $\phi$ and satisfies the Lorenz gauge. i.e.
$$\nabla \cdot {\bf A} = {\bf k}\cdot {\bf A_0} f'$$
and
$$-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{c^2}{\omega}{\bf k}\cdot {\bf A_0}(-\omega f') = {\bf k}\cdot {\bf A_0}f'   $$

So your answer appears to be
$$ \phi = \frac{c^2}{\omega} {\bf k}\cdot {\bf A}$$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the residual gauge freedom of the Lorenz gauge ($A^\mu \rightarrow A^\mu - \partial^\mu\chi$ where $\Box\chi = 0$) allows setting $\phi = 0$ while remaining in the Lorenz gauge.

Comment: Indeed it does, and in which case, the A-field and $\vec{k}$ are perpendicular. @AlfredCentauri

Comment: Thankyou very much! I think this is the answer. Prove come from ${\nabla ^2}\phi  + \frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {\nabla  \cdot {\bf{A}}} \right) = 0$, with plane wave assumption, we have $k^2 \phi = \omega \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{A}$  which is a equivalent to relation you give.